# I'm moving and have stray cat I don't want to leave behind. But he won't come inside at all

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, strays

I'm moving and have stray cat I don't want to leave behind. This question is different than the another one posted, because this stray (not feral) cat won't come inside the house nor will he even go inside the cat shelter I built for him.

I've been caring for this outside cat for about a year now. It took several months for him to trust me, and he still doesn't completely trust my boyfriend.

He comes around when I call or waits for me every morning. He loves to be petted, but I have four inside cats and he also has no interest in coming inside.

I've tried getting him on back patio in rain and he won't come. I'm moving out of state and I don't want leave him. He has become dependant upon me.

What can I do? Can he be safely relocated with me? I love the little guy so much.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that he never comes inside makes me suspect that he has a home *somewhere else*. If the cat doesn't enter your house, then I don't think it considers itself to be living with you. Taking the cat with you might tear it away from its actual home.

I would suggest you don't take the cat with you. If you're worried about who will take care of him, try and get a neighbor involved while you are still there (so you can introduce them to each other).

Comment: also put a collar on him with the contact details, so if he has a home they will call.